# List Comprehension for multi label counter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have already made below code, and its working fine, however I am trying to make more readable and optimised code for this i am to replace my code to list comprehension to replace all "if conditions" for finding emotion_class(in double **).

Trying to optimise ** code into list comprehension:

```
emotion_classes = ["Joy", "Fear", "Anger", "Surprise","Sadness", "Trust","Anticipation"]

[increaseCounterofJoy,increaseCounterofFear, for emotion in emotion_classes]
```

Code

```
for idx in range(len(df_split)):

    iter_df = df_split[idx]

    i = 0

    final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("Date","Joy", "Fear", "Anger", "Surprise","Sadness", "Trust","Anticipation"))

    for index, row in iter_df.iterrows():

        **if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Joy":
            row["Joy"] = +1
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Fear":
            row["Fear"] = +1  
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Anger":
            row["Anger"] = +1
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Surprise":
            row["Surprise"] = +1
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Sadness":
            row["Sadness"] = +1
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Trust":
            row["Trust"] = +1
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] = "Anticipation":
            row["Anticipation"] = +1**

        final_df.loc[i] = row["Date"], row["Joy"], row["Fear"], row["Anger"], row["Surprise"], row["Sadness"], row["Trust"], row["Anticipation"]

    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I have never seen the `**` operator used like that...

Comment: Wait is that just highlighting where we're supposed to be looking?

Comment: He's just using it to mark a region, see the last line of the if chain

Comment: it's just "**" to mark the code. Anyway, `=` isn't correct. Code isn't running as is. Also `=+1` typo

Comment: I was trying to bold the code but stack overflow make them with **

Comment: Sample `df` please

Comment: Questions about code that works belong on  codereview.stackexchange.com. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I think you need `cumcount()` but sample data needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a pivot table?

```
In [1]: iter_df
Out[1]:
   Date Emotion Class
0     1           Joy
1     1         Peace
2     2           Joy
3     3         Peace
4     3         Peace

In [2]: iter_df['ones'] = 1

In [3]: pd.pivot_table(iter_df, index='Date', columns='Emotion Class', values='ones', margins=False, aggfunc='sum')
    ...:
Out[3]:
Emotion Class  Joy  Peace
Date
1              1.0    1.0
2              1.0    NaN
3              NaN    2.0
```

Comment: Well pivot_table will give the mean value when agg not specified. I don't think OP needed pivot table.

Comment: Thanks Final_df: all emotion class with number of emotion class counts +1 is counter for example Joy:10, Anger:15, Sadness:25... like this

Comment: I don't get the difference... are you just saying that you want to handle duplicate emotions per date? The code handles that, I've updated the data in the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: And if you don't want the date as the DataFrame index, just use `.reset_index()` and it'll get turned back into a column, exactly like the output of the code in your question

Comment: Thanks scnerd, this is exactly I am trying to do i also read pd.pivot_table its fit for my requirement thanks again

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a task where a list comprehension is useful. Just use a traditional `for` loop:

```
emotion_classes = [
    "Joy", "Fear", "Anger", "Surprise",
    "Sadness", "Trust","Anticipation",
]

for index, row in iter_df.iterrows():
    for emotion in emotion_classes:
        if iter_df["Emotion Class"] == emotion:
            row[emotion] += 1
```

There are a couple of typos in your code. You have `=` instead of `==` in your tests. And I assume you want to increment the appropriate fields in `row`, rather than just setting them to `+1`.

Comment: plus it fixes 2 nasty typos.

Answer (score 1):

PM 2Ring's answer works, but I'm wondering if you can't simplify it more to:

```
for index, row in iter_df.iterrows():    
    row[iter_df["Emotion Class"]] += 1
```

Comment: Good call. I guess that would work. I'm not familiar with pandas, but I assume that it can handle missing keys, eg if the current`iter_df["Emotion Class"]` key doesn't yet exist in `row`.